# Deploying a flask application with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, flask, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy one of my Flask apps to mod_wsgi on apache, but I'm having trouble because apache tries to solve SOME of the routes on the filesystem:

**apache's error_log:**

```
[Mon Aug 06 19:18:38 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: 
/srv/http/webchat/src/_publish_message, referer: http://localhost:88/webchat/chat
```

I'm saying "SOME of the routes" because the authentication (on "/") and redirection to "/chat" works.

The route "_publish_message" is accessed via AJAX like this (using jQuery):

```
function publish_message(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('/_publish_message', {'message': "user's message taken from a text field"})
        .fail(Handler.publish_error);
}
```

The route "_sse_stream" is used as the URL for an EventSource.

These two aren't working!

The virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
    ServerName webchat.dev

    WSGIDaemonProcess webchat user=http group=http threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /webchat /srv/http/webchat/src/webchat.wsgi
    WSGIScriptReloading On

    DocumentRoot /srv/http/webchat/src

    <Directory /srv/http/webchat/src>
        WSGIProcessGroup webchat
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `webchat.wsgi` file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/srv/http/webchat/src')
from index import app as application
```

A basic "hello world" app deployed to `mod_wsgi` runs OK.
My flask app, when run using the development server integrated into flask, behaves well.

Comment: "The route "_publish_message" is accessed via AJAX". Can you provide more details on this ?

Comment: I added the code that does the AJAX request.

Comment: I am not sure but may be this could help. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/

Comment: @codegeek That did it, The $SCRIPT_ROOT part, to be precise I added `$SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_publish_message'` as the URL where the AJAX request is made. Please add  your answer so I can accept it, others may benefit from this.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Added as a answer. Please accept.

Comment: I've used mod_wsgi a number of times. But, why do you/we hate Python? :D reminds me of http://pyvideo.org/video/83/djangocon-2011--keynote---glyph-lefkowitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this link to follow the correct process. You have to use the $SCRIPT_ROOT variable.

[flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery)